# Circle radius < stroke width. Inconsistent results

Tags: svg

Is the SVG format well defined for the case where the circle radius is smaller than the stroke width? Here's an example.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1280" height="720">
  <g id="fig16" style="stroke:rgb(255,203,0);fill:rgb(255,203,0)">
    <circle cx="409" cy="322" r="0.005" style="stroke-width:20.687"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When viewed in the Edge browser it either appears or disappears depending on the level of zoom I use in the browser. In Inkscape it's shown with an outline and a diamond shape in the middle, which changes when I zoom in. I get varying results when I use other SVG viewers. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve avoiding it completely?

Comment: Is it well defined? Yes. Do UAs generally have bugs when you try it? Also yes.

Comment: Thanks Robert. So my question is, what would be the well defined result in this case? I guess it should show the circle as a single filled circle? My next question would be what is the well defined result when the object has opacity set? Should the circle have uniform colour or would there be a darker area in the center where it overlaps itself?

Comment: A single filled circle. There should be a single uniform colour if you set opacity < 1